# Phoenix Dialyzer Changeset Warning

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, dialyzer

Dialyzer complains about Phoenix models when they are set up in the usual way, i.e.

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty)
...
```

the params instruct how the model is to be updated, with :empty as a default to differentiate between a blank form submission with 'params' equal to an empty map.

Dialyzer warns:

```
The call 'Elixir.Backend.Plot':
changeset(x0@1::any(),'empty') will never return since it differs in the 2nd argument from the success typing arguments: 
(#{},#{})
```

if I remove the ':empty' default param the warning disappears.

Is there a spec which satisfies the type checker while keeping the usual default changeset function? Any hints or pointers?

Comment: You might also find it helpful to read this: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to advise you about exactly what you should do to deal with this since I don't know the exact type spec you're providing.  However, I think if you mark that second parameter as potentially being an empty map it should work as you want.

Look [here](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-January/082451.html).  It seems as if maps aren't specifically supported by dialyzer but there seems to be a relatively simple workaround.  Make the specification `#{ any() => any() }` However, as is mentioned in that message it's not totally clear if that will work with empty maps or not.

---

EDIT:

It appears that I was a little bit unclear in my response.  When I say "spec" I mean that annotation that you add above the function to tell dialyzer how you expect your function to behave.  For example:

```
  @spec get_short_name(Path.t)::Path.t
  def get_short_name(path) when is_binary(path) do
```

If you haven't specified any @spec at all then that may be your issue.

In the case you specified above, I'd suggest that something like this may work:

```
@spec changeset(#{any() => any()}, #{any() => any()})::returntype
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty)
```

You'd want to modify *returntype* to be whatever type changeset returns and I can't tell from the fragment you posted what the type of *model* should be so I guessed it's a map. As I say, since I don't know the details of what you're doing with changeset and since you don't seem to have specified a @spec, it's sort of tough for me to say.

Comment: hey, there's no spec applied, it's just vanilla code. ideally i want to keep the :empty atom, which isn't an empty map obviously...

Comment: @user3264325 Look at my edit to the answer.  By the way, really don't appreciate the downvote.

Comment: As @OnorioCatenacci suggests, there is somewhere a type specification for `changeset` which requires the second argument to be a map. If you also want/have to allow the atom `empty`, the specification should reflect that by being e.g. `map() | 'empty'`.

Comment: downvote was not me! (i don't really understand the interface, newish here, but double checked my profile, and in actual fact I never voted on anything here before : ) will investigate the edited reply and get back to you. thx again